# How to authenticate a regular Yammer user automatically from a Java program in a SSO enabled network?

Tags: java, rest, authentication, single-sign-on, yammer

I am trying to write an external Java application that collects posts from Yammer using its REST API and I am experiencing issues with the authentication part.

To extract the data I want a regular yammer user (I do not have admin permissions) to be authenticated automatically from the Java application without any prompts. Does anyone know whether this is feasible and moreover - whether it is feasible in a SSO-enabled network? If yes, what kind of authentication libraries should I use? Is there some documentation/sample code snippet describing how to log in to Yammer via Java and not via a Yammer app?

I've seen that there are similar questions here, but are still unanswered.

I will appreciate any know-how on the topic!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only way to authenticate to yammer without any prompt is to pass a persistent oauth token as an authorization bearer token in your request header. The caveat is, users cannot be dynamic.

Comment: might you have example code using spring-social or spring-security on how a yammer call can be made in the scenario?

Comment: This is an AngularJS example code - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/israelo/2015/02/23/consuming-yammer-restful-api-with-angularjs-for-dummies/ . Alternatively, you may use ADAL (java) library -  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/israelo/2016/07/05/yammer-apis-and-adal-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to generate the access token. For that you need client Id and client Secret.Steps are available in **https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/test-token**. 
But if you don't have that information, go to https://developer.yammer.com and log on with the credentials and try some Rest API(Try It Out section) in the developer site. Copy the Authorization code from the Request Headers and you can use it in your application.
Note:   Access Tokens for users are long lived, expiring when users are suspended, change their Yammer password (non-SSO networks only), or users manually revoke them